# Ruby/Tk: how to get smaller button widget with image

Tags: ruby, image, button, tk-toolkit

I'm coding on Tk 8.5.9 from ActiveTcl on Ruby 1.8.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.

To meet my application requirements I need to make the button widgets as small as the gif image but I am not able to. I have been hours searching and experimenting with negative results.

Greatly thankful in advance for any clues.

Following is the code i am trying to get small buttons from.

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'

$up_img = TkPhotoImage.new("file"=>"arrowup-n.gif")
$down_img = TkPhotoImage.new("file"=>"arrowdown-n.gif")

root = TkRoot.new {title "Ek Composer"}

content = Tk::Tile::Frame.new(root).pack
Tk::Tile::Button.new(content) {width 1;image $up_img;  command {move_up}  }.pack
Tk::Tile::Button.new(content) {width 1;image $down_img;command {move_down}}.pack

def move_up
    p "move up"
end

def move_down
    p "move down"
end

Tk.mainloop
```

But the buttons remain too big :(.

Answer (score 2):

It's awkward. The OSX theme *really* wants to add extra space at either end of the button.

You can try switching to the classic button (in `tk` itself) but that puts more space vertically and looks a bit less native. Or you can put the image in a label (which you can shrink exactly) and add bindings to it to make it respond to mouse clicks.

Comment: I will try your latest suggestion adding binding to a label.

Comment: I added binding to label. Works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I added binding to label. Works fine. Thanks. Follows a code snippet of label with binding as button.

```
require 'tk'


$resultsVar = TkVariable.new
root = TkRoot.new
root.title = "Window"

$up_img = TkPhotoImage.new("file"=>"arrowup-n.gif")
$down_img = TkPhotoImage.new("file"=>"arrowdown-n.gif")

Lbl = TkLabel.new(root) do
  image $up_img
  borderwidth 0
  font TkFont.new('times 20 bold')
  foreground  "red"
  relief      "groove"
  pack("side" => "right",  "padx"=> "50", "pady"=> "50")
end

Lbl.bind("ButtonPress-1")  {
    Lbl.configure("image"=>$down_img) 
}

Lbl.bind("ButtonRelease-1") { 
    Lbl.configure("image"=>$up_img) 
}

Lbl['textvariable'] = $resultsVar
$resultsVar.value = 'New value to display'

Tk.mainloop
```